# How do I start extracting information from the provided html files

Tags: java

I am trying to read, detect, extract, and print information from provided html files.  I understand how the code is supposed to work and the process that I need to take going from file to file.  I just can't seem to get this thing started.  Any suggestions or input would be appreciated.  Here is the code that I was provided

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean more = true;
       
       while (more){
           
           System.out.println("Lookup by M)ajor, or Q)uit");
           String cmd = in.nextLine();
           
           if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
               more = false;
               
           }else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("M")){
               
               System.out.println("Enter major:");
               String major = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
               Scanner ins;
               
                        
               String inputFileName = major + ".html";
               FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(inputFileName);
               ins = new Scanner(inputFile);

               String courseinfo = "";
               
               // INSERT CODE TO:
               // read each line, detect if the line contains the course information
               // extract and print the information
```

Comment: You should post problem of your code,not just ask solution.[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You've only posted part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting if the line has course information depends on what information you are looking for and what is in these files. I assume they all have a similar format in order for this to work.

What I would do is:

1. Copy the entire file into a local String.
2. Parse the string for the information you are looking for

1:

```
String file = ""; 
while( ins.hasNextLine() ) { 
     file = file + ins.nextLine()+ '\n'; 
}
```

2. Lets say that the course info is all contained within the body of the web page

```
if ( ( file.contains("<body>") == false) || ( file.contains("</body>") == false ) 
     continue; //Move on to next iteration 

file = file.substring(file.indexOf("<body>" + 6, file.indexOf"</body>" ); 
System.out.println("Information on " + major + ": " + file);
```

#2 could be more complicated depending on what you are looking for, but this is the basic idea.

Check out the documentation for the Java String methods, these will be critical in parsing out the important stuff

If this doesn't work let me know.